# How do I get Index of Listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I can the correct index of listview using this code:

```
$('#listview').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert( $(this).index());
});
```

This returns the correct index.

However if using this code, it always returns 0:

```
$('#listview').on('click', 'div', function() {
    alert( $(this).index());
});
```

I use second code to differentiate the click event among different divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index gives you the position of the element relative to its siblings in the HTML tree. if your div is within the li and your HTML looks like this

```
<ul id="listview">
   <li><div>First div for click handler</div></li>
   <li><div>Second div for click handler</div></li>
</ul>
```

Then 0 is the correct index for any div in the listview. Maybe you need something like this

```
$(this).closest('li').index();
```

in your click handler.

Comment: Nice ans short answer, congrats

Comment: ¡De nada! - gern geschehen